# Mongoose Populate response returns null

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have a database in MongoDB with two collections: Users and Contacts. In my project I have two models: User and Contact. Every User has an array with his contacts and every contact has a property owner that stores the id of the user that contains that contact. These are my models:

```js
export const contactSchema = new Schema({
  phoneNumber: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  owner: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
});

const Contact = model("Contact", contactSchema, "contacts");


const userSchema = new Schema({
  phoneNumber: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  contacts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Contact" }],
});

const User = model("User", userSchema, "users");

export default User;
```

Now, I'm trying to make a function that receives a request, response and next function and returns in the response an array with all the contacts of the user id '631791f8d7342693105b6908':

```js
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import Contact from "../../../database/models/Contact/Contact";

const getContacts = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const contacts = await Contact.findOne({
      _id: "631791f8d7342693105b6908",
    }).populate("owner");

    res.status(200).json({ contacts });
};

export default getContacts;
```

In my mongoDB I have a contact that contains the owner with that id, but when I make the request the response is:

```js
{
  "contacts": null
}
```

How can I make for get in the response the contact that has as owner the id porvided before?

If anyone can help me I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: `.populate()` isn't the issue, `.findOne()` is, that's what's returning the `null`. In other words, your query didn't yield a result. Did you mean `findOne({ owner : "631791f8d7342693105b6908" })` perhaps?

Comment: Yes! @robertklep that was the solution. I also changed `findOne` for `find` for receive all contacts with that owner, not only one Contact. Post it like an answer and I review it like good. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `null` suggests that the query yields no results at all (which is unrelated to `.populate()`).

From what you're describing, you want to search for contacts where the owner matches a particular id, so the query should be:

```
const contacts = await Contact.findOne({
  owner: "631791f8d7342693105b6908",
}).populate("owner");
```

As you state in your comment, use `.find()` if you want to find *all* contacts belonging to a particular owner.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
```

```js
const contacts = await Contact.findOne({
  owner: new ObjectId("631791f8d7342693105b6908"),
}).populate("owner");
```